# createQueryBuilder warning Undefined variable: list

Tags: arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

When I Run createQueryBuilder Query by passing Array as a parameter value showing as array undefined.

```
    $list = array('13','197');

    $queryBuilder = function($repo) use ($user) {
    return $repo->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where('p.id IN (:stores)')
        ->setParameter('stores',$list);
        ->orderBy('p.name', 'ASC'); 
    }
```

Comment: I think that you posted here not the actual code you have. Because this code have no problems.

Comment: I Updated the Complete Script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include your `$list` variable in lambda-function scope. To do that you need to provide this variable in `use`-part of lambda-function definition:

```
$list = array('13','197');
$queryBuilder = function($repo) use ($user, $list) {
    return $repo->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where('p.id IN (:stores)')
        ->setParameter('stores',$list);
        ->orderBy('p.name', 'ASC'); 
}
```